# html get elements dropdownlist vbnet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am trying to collect all the items of an html dropdownlist and put them in my combobx in vbet but i am getting an error that index was out of range.I have checked the id of the dropdownlist but it is correct.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim I As Integer = 0
    Dim NAME As String


    NAME = WebBrowser1.document.GetElementById("ID").GetAttribute("pt1:r1:0:soc2::content").GetAttribute("value").ElementAt(I)
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(NAME)
    MessageBox.Show(NAME)



End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: <select id="pt1:r1:0:soc2::content" name="pt1:r1:0:soc2" style="max-width:350px;" class="x2h">
<option title="" value="" _adftmpopt="t"></option>
<option title="MENU1" value="0">MENU1</option>
<option title="MENU2" value="1">MENU2</option>

Comment: The html code is above.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote this code now and everything works perfect.

hope it helps:

```
For Each elem In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pt1:r1:0:soc2::content").Children
     ComboBox1.Items.Add(WebBrowser1.Document.Body.AppendChild(elem).InnerText)
     MessageBox.Show(WebBrowser1.Document.Body.AppendChild(elem).InnerText)
Next
```

Jonathan

Comment: @DimitrisDimitri I see you are new to the site. If this answer is working for you, I'd suggest accepting the answer by clicking the check mark. That and voting answers up are the best way to say thanks here.